# How do I obtain the ebony blade and how do I power it up?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The ebony blade is a katana like two handed weapon in Skyrim.  Its apparently associated with one of the daedric quests, but which one, and how do I start it?

Also, once I obtain it, how do I power it up?

[image: Ebony Blade]

Comment: Easiest way I can think of is to smith an ebony blade and upgrade it with a life steal enchant.

Comment: @Domocus, I really hope that was a tongue in cheek response :P

Comment: Anyone know how to use console commands to fully power up the Ebony Blade as fast as possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The *Ebony Blade* is the reward for the Daedric quest *The Whispering Door*. You can begin the quest once you reach level 20 and:

> You defeated the dragon terrorizing Whiterun early in the main questline.

To start the quest, ask the innkeeper in Whiterun about any rumors he might've heard.

The *Ebony Blade* is a most sinister weapon. Its description says:

> Strengthened by the blood of deceit.

To do that:

> You must kill the people who you've befriended/done favors for in the ultimate act of betrayal. Every 2 kills increases its life leach .

Comment: what do you mean by increasing its power, do you mean blade damage?

Comment: @yx. judging by the UESP reference, it increases the strength of the absorb health enchant (from 10 up to 30).

Comment: @Raven Thanks for that update, now I need to go find myself this wicked wicked blade.

Comment: It also silences for several seconds so is great against spellcasters.

Comment: Maxs out the upgrade if you kill your spouse with it...

Comment: @Drkbrthrhdlstnr Do you have any supporting evidence for that?

Comment: @Drkbrthrhdlstnr I tested killing my spouse on the PC version, it didn't max out

Comment: It looks like killing your spouse is *supposed* to max the blade, but it currently does not.

Answer (score 2):

I obtained mine by inspecting Jarl Balgruuf's children (Look at inns or ask people for rumors of his children being "weird") Then you go to talk to his son, which then speaks of the "Whispering Door". Once that happens, you'll have to aquire the key either by killing or pickpocketing the Court Wizard or the Jarl himself. Unlock the door, then the Ebony Blade is there.

Comment: The **Ebony Blade** is a specific daedric artifact. It is distinct from an ordinary Ebony sword, which you seem to be describing.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Um well I was just saying how to obtain it, clearly what the question asks.